# Fazer um POST com AJAX e JSON com Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, json

tenho o seguinte código em jQuery

```
$.post('/privmsg?', {
    folder: 'inbox',
    mode: 'post',
    post: '1',
    username: 'Wagner',
    subject: 'Título',
    message: 'Mensagem'
});
```

Eu estou estudando Javascript, e gostaria de fazer o mesmo efeito com Javascript puro.

Eu fiz algumas pesquisas e aprendi a fazer requisições com GET com AJAX, agora gostaria de saber, como faço esse POST com Javascript puro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo o site [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/), a sintaxe é essa:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/my/url', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.send(data);
```

Tenha este site em seus favoritos para sempre que quiser fazer algo sem jQuery. Bem no alto você escolhe se quer ver a versão IE8+, IE9+ ou IE10+.

A versão acima é compatível com IE8+.

Comment: Entendo, mas uma coisa que não aprendi ainda, é passar os dados (data) com JSON, você teria algum exemplo de como faze-lo?

Comment: Como assim não usar jQuery? Heresia! Veja: [When is “use jQuery” not a valid answer to a JavaScript question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question) e [essa imagem ilustrativa](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif). ;)

Comment: @waghcwb Simplesmente crie um array com `{}` como fez com jQuery

Comment: @Anthony Pois é. Benchmarks mostram que o jQuery é lento, o problema é ficar sem a compatibilidade com browsers e a tonelada de plugins que exigem o jQuery.

Comment: Concordo com o Andrey, jQuery nem sempre é viável. Alguns projetos é interessante usar, mas outros eu mesmo não vejo necessidade.. @Andrey, eu fiz desta maneira, mas sem resultados: http://pastebin.com/TQd90hyw

Comment: @waghcwb Estranho, achei que assim era pra funcionar.

Comment: @Andrey, Eu consegui um resultado satisfatório da seguinte maneira: http://pastebin.com/AWyQqRq7
Porém não consegui fazer com JSON. Estranho..

Comment: Eu penso da seguinte forma, nos programadores somos maetros, temos que saber utilizar o máximo de recursos e de forma segura e eficiente. Trabalhe com os 2, faça testes, cheque os processos, busque formas já criadas.
Site do Mozilla também é muito rico com java script e outros derivados. =D