# JavaScript XMLHttpRequest Scope Function

Tags: javascript, json

```
function getMensages(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '../mensagens.php');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload=function(){
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            jsonText = xhr.responseText;
            jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
        }
       return jsonObj;
   }
}

getMensages();

console.log(jsonObj);
```

Como faço para pegar a variável `jsonObj` fora do escopo da função `xhr.onload()` e fora da função `getMensages()`? Ao chamar a função `xhr.onload()` já esta retornando objeto que quero mas preciso do objeto na variável fora dos escopos.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26767/fazer-um-post-com-ajax-e-json-com-javascript-puro?rq=1

Comment: Podes colocar o dado numa variável global: `window.jsonObj  = jsonObj;`

Comment: Bom dia Kadu, talvez a sua questão parece ser sobre callbacks, talvez está resposta lhe ajude: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45721/3635

Answer (score 3):

Para teres essa variável no escopo global podes fazer `window.jsonObj  = jsonObj;` (que é melhor que defenir sem usar `var`), mas isso não vai resolver o problema. Lembra-te que o AJAX á asincrono e quando fizeres a chamada o valor só vai ser passado para a variável `jsonObj` quando o servidor responder, o que implica que o código que tens já correu e o `console.log()` foi registado sem a variável ter sido preenchida.

Tens de adaptar o teu código para correr dentro da função `xhr.onload`. No caso do teu código esse `console.log()` devia lá estar para registar o valor certo.

```
xhr.onload=function(){
    if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
        jsonText = xhr.responseText;
        jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
        console.log(jsonObj);  // aqui será chamado quando a resposta tiver chegado
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMensages(callback){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '../mensagens.php');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload=function(){
        if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
            jsonText = xhr.responseText;
            jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
            if(callback) callback(jsonObj);
        }
       //return jsonObj;
   }
}

var cback = function(jsonObj) {
  console.log(jsonObj);
};

getMensages(cback);
```